# How to use ServerName to rename localhost to www.domain.com in Apache 2.4?

Tags: apache

I am trying to configure the httpd.conf to rename localhost:80/webapp to www.domain.com/webapp. The current configuration I have now is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName  www.domain.com
  ServerAlias domain.com
  ProxyPass        /webapp http://localhost:8080/webapp/
  ProxyPassReverse /webapp http://localhost:8080/webapp/
</VirtualHost>
```

I used this configuration but whenever I tried to browse "www.domain.com/webapp" it goes to some other website, the normal www.domain.com website and somewhere outside the VirtualHost tag I have

```
ServerName localhost:80
```

The Web App is a Spring MVC project using JSP, do I need to set the  documentroot to the Spring MVC project ? How do I do that ?

Do I need to buy a domain for this to work ?

How should I configure the httpd.conf to rename localhost:80/webapp to www.domain.com/webapp?

Comment: Off topic, and [tag:spring] has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the configuration file /etc/hosts with nano:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Add the ip and domain to the `/etc/hosts` file. For example:

```
172.15.12.123 domain.com
```

or

```
127.0.0.1 domain.com
```

in case the server is running on your local machine.

Comment: Yes, I can do this but I wanted to do this the configuring Apache 2.4 way for learning purpose.